# How to use jQuery to disable a CSS rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8xbya33/) to describe the situation
I have a table which has cells that light up with a border on hover:

```
table td:hover {
  border: 2px solid #3d8b40;
}
```

When one of them is pressed, I want to make it have a permanent border mentioned above and while it's active (until the next click), I want to disable the lighting on other cells.

The problem seems to have a simple solution to give all cells a class that prevents the border during activation:

```
.no-border:not(.active):hover {
  border: inherit !important;
}
```

But there is a lot of cells and I'm afraid that toggling so many classes at once may impact the performance.
Then I also tried this approach:

```
$('td').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('table td:hover').css('border', 'inherit');
  }
  else {
    $('table td:hover').css('border', '2px solid #3d8b40');
  }
}
```

The problem with it was that the `:hover` selector only targeted one cell - the one I was pointing at, and I couldn't figure out how to spread this rule to all of them. And that basically means adding an inline style to an HTML element, which is not better than adding a class when considering performance.

How could I solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe add a class to the container element instead of to every cell?

Comment: overwrite it with inline css important is an option? `$('table td').attr('style', ':hover {"border": "inherit !important"}')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle with a solution
https://jsfiddle.net/a8xbya33/1/

```
table.enable_hover td:hover {
  border: 2px solid #3d8b40;
}

<table class="enable_hover">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$('td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

  $('table').toggleClass('enable_hover');
})
```

Add a class to the table that enables the hover (CSS rule). When the user clicks on a , you can toggle this class too.